# Get display resolution inside Remote Desktop from windows command line

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, resolution

When I connect to another computer using Remote Desktop, How can I obtain, from Windows Command line in a batch, the screen resolution of the Remote Desktop window, not the screen resolution of the remote server desktop ?

For example if I connect with Rdp to a server with screen resolution 1920x1080 with a Rdp window of 1024x900:

```
mstsc /w:1024 /h:900 /v:remote_host
```

and inside the Rdp I try to get the resolution with wmic, i.e.

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth
ScreenHeight  ScreenWidth
1080          1920
```

That is the server but not the Rdp resolution. How can be obtained the Rdp screen resolution ?

Answer (score 7):

The following command should give you both the configured display resolution as well as the RDP resolution:

```
wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription
```

When connected via RDP, output should look something like this:

```
VideoModeDescription
1920 x 1080 x 4294967296 colors
1704 x 942 x 4294967296 colors
```